# Nim infinite loop

Tags: loops, nim-lang

Hi I want an infinite loop in nim. Not a function that inifnitely sleeps, it has to be a loop.

Tried writing this

```
while true:
  ;
```

But the compiler says that it expects an expression. When I put an expression into the body of the loop, i.e.

```
while true:
  0
```

The compiler says that the expression is not used and refuses to compile my program. An obvious hack to that is to cast the expression to `void`, the expressions of this type get discarded.

```
while true:
  cast[void](0)
```

But now the compiler expects `void` as a parameter to the void cast

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `discard` statement:

```
while true:
  discard
```